# What does 'anterodorsal' mean?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, terminology

In the context of places of articulation of consonants, what does "anterodorsal" mean?

I came across it in the 2008 paper by Wai-Sum Lee: [The Articulation of the Coronal Sounds in the Peking Dialect](https://issp2008.loria.fr/Proceedings/PDF/issp2008-21.pdf)

> Palatograms and linguograms show that the syllable-initial (i) ‘d’ is apico-laminal denti-alveolar [t]; (ii) ‘s z’ are laminal alveolar or denti-alveolar [s̻ ts̻] ; (iii) ‘sh zh r’ are apical postalveolar or pre-palatal [ʃ̺ tʃ̺ ɺ̠̺]; and (iv) ‘x j’ are anterodorsal postalveolar or alveolo-postalveolar [ʃ tʃ]

Answer (score 2):

Where "postalveolar" in the description of the sound [ʃ] refers to the location on the roof of the mouth, anterodorsal refers to the location on the tongue. It does not seem to be a specific region on the tongue, but vaguely it's a combination of 'anterior' (front) and 'dorsal' (the back of the tongue). It's the front part of the dorsum. As you can tell when you pronounce the sound, the region that moves up toward the roof of the mouth is farther back. You can see from the linguogram in the Methods section the channel of constricted air where the tongue does not touch the painted palate, which is similar to the image for 'j.' Also lol I didn't know that they did this by painting with charcoal in people's mouths.

*Best*,
Matthew

Comment: Painting with a mixture of charcoal _and_ some kind of resinous gum (guar gum?). Very disgusting to have in your mouth, and you can’t swallow or do anything until the palatogram is done. Highly useful, but not pleasant.